# Facebook Graph API Retrieving Closed Group Videos and Live Videos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an app for a client who uses a closed group on facebook for their customers. In it they post videos and also live videos.

I would like to embed the videos and past live videos in the app and also be able to watch the live video when they are live.

I've had limited success in testing this using the graph API. I am logging in using an account, which is a member of the group and I have also added the admin of the group as an admin of the app in the Facebook developer settings.

When I try to retrieve a standard video that has been posted to the group (so not a live video, or past live video) I get the error:

> *message = "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit
>   this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our
>   documentation on reviewable features:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.";*

I have read a post somewhere on the internet where if I have the admin of the group as a role in the facebook developer settings then I shouldn't get the error above. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

When I try to retrieve a past live video then I get the error:

> *message = "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1337249189746920' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does
>   not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api";*

I think this is because I do not have the right permissions but I am unsure as to what permission I am missing as I have read the permissions reference document and thought I had covered it all.

The permissions for my access token are:

user_videos, email, publish_video, manage_pages, pages_show_list, groups_access_member_info, public_profile

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?

Comment: api reference: "Use of this endpoint requires App Review". btw, some permissions are for pages, not groups: manage_pages, pages_show_list. and public_profile is for user profiles.

Comment: btw, fyi: i remove the ios and sdk tags, because your question is general and there is no ios/swift code in it, or code with the ios sdk.

Comment: Thanks @luschn. I read somewhere that if my app is in development on the Facebook developers portal and that the group admin is on the roles then I should be able to test the end points?